# Import VARRAY from a CSV file using Datagrip

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I have a .csv file where my data are stored. I am trying to import them in my table using the "Import Data from File" option within DataGrip. The problem is i keep facing errors when it comes to my VARRAY column. It does not recognise my data as such and the import fails.

The column type is a custom one :

`create type histogram as VARRAY (256) of double precision;`

And here is the table :

```
create table multimedia
(
    nom               varchar2(50),
    image             ordsys.ordimage,
    signature         ordsys.ordimageSignature,
    couleur           integer,
    Contour           integer,
    TauxDeRouge       float,
    TauxDeVert        float,
    TauxDeBleu        float,
    MoyenneDuGradient float,
    Histogramme       histogram
);
```

I have tried a lot of different data format inside the CSV file for the VARRAY field, such as :

`(data1, data2, ... , dataN)`

`histogram(data1, data2, ... , dataN)`

Here is the error output from DataGrip :

`2:1: ORA-00932: inconsistent types of data ;expected:Y2019MYDIRECTORY_MYNAME.HISTOGRAM ; got: CHAR`

You will find here one CSV entry : 
https://pastebin.com/raw/Kta9GQjw

So, how can DataGrip interpret this part of my .csv as a VARRAY ? ( The image and signature fields are not to be imported using the .csv and datagrip. They are so not inside the .csv file and it has no incidence on my issue since DataGrip interprets the first line as a header and ingest the data to the corresponding tables. )

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported yet. Please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9235